# mysql keyword search across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, search, keyword, multiple-columns

Various incarnations of this question have been asked here before, but I thought I'd give it another shot.

I had a terrible database layout. A single entity (widget) was split into two tables:

`CREATE TABLE widgets (widget_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment)`

`CREATE TABLE widget_data (
widget_id int(10), 
field ENUM('name','size','color','brand'), 
data TEXT)`

this was less that ideal. if wanted to find widgets of a specific name, color and brand, i had to do a three-way join on the widget_data table. so I converted to the reasonable table type:

`CREATE TABLE widgets (widget_id int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(32),size INT(3),color VARCHAR(16), brand VARCHAR(32))`

This makes most queries much better. But it makes searching harder. It used to be that if i wanted to search widgets for, say, '%black%', I would just `SELECT * FROM widget_data WHERE data LIKE '%black%'`. This would give me all instances of widgets that are black in color, or are made by blackwell industries, or whatever. I would even know exactly which field matched, and could show that to my user.

how do I execute a similar search using the new table layout? I could of course do `WHERE name LIKE '%black%' OR size LIKE '%black%'...` but that seems clunky, and I still don't know which fields matched. I could run a separate query for each column I want to match on, which would give me all matches and how they matched, but that would be a performance hit.  any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two conflicting requirements. You want to search as if all your data is in a single field, but you also want to identify which specific field was matched.

There's nothing wrong with your `WHERE name LIKE '%black%' OR size LIKE '%black%'...`  expression. It's a perfectly valid search on the table as you have defined it. Why not just check the results in code to see which one matched? It's a minimal overhead.

If you want a cleaner syntax for your SQL then you could create a view on the table, adding an extra field which consists of concatenating the other fields:

```
CREATE VIEW extra_widget_data AS
  SELECT (name, size, color, brand,
          CONCAT(name, size, color, brand) as all_fields)
  FROM widget_data;
```

Then you'd have to add an index on this field, which requires more space, CPU time to maintain etc. I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 4):

You can include part of `WHERE` expression into selecting columns. For example:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (name LIKE '%black%') AS name_matched,
  (size LIKE '%black%') AS size_matched
FROM widget_data 
WHERE name LIKE '%black%' OR size LIKE '%black%'...
```

Then check value of `name_matched` on side of the script.

Not sure how it will affect performance. Feal free to test it before going to production

Comment: I was looking for the like search part, but the column name like is brilliant! Thank you for sharing

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into MySQL full text search capability, this enables you to match against multiple columns of varchar type.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: the table in question is innodb, and cannot be changed to myisam, so full-text index is unfortunately not an option

Comment: Full-text indexes can be used with InnoDB or MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.